# Referencing an aligned empty struct in C?

Tags: c, gcc, struct, padding, memory-alignment

I came across an odd set of macros in the SameBoy emulator (v0.13) that seems to use an empty struct to address data. It looks like this:

```cpp
#define GB_PADDING(type, old_usage) type old_usage##__do_not_use

#define GB_SECTION(name, ...)     \
        __attribute__ ((aligned (8))) struct {} name##_section_start;  \
        __VA_ARGS__;   \
        struct {} name##_section_end
#define GB_SECTION_OFFSET(name)   \
        (offsetof(GB_gameboy_t, name##_section_start))
#define GB_SECTION_SIZE(name)     \ 
        (offsetof(GB_gameboy_t, name##_section_end) - offsetof(GB_gameboy_t, name##_section_start))
#define GB_GET_SECTION(gb, name)  \
        ((void*)&((gb)->name##_section_start))
```

It seems `GB_gameboy_t` is a type of some kind (probably for the GameBoy internal structure). However the part that is bothering me is the `GB_SECTION` and `GB_GET_SECTION` macros. It is clear that the purpose of these macros is to align data. However, I am lost on what an empty struct (labeled `name##_section_start`) expands to. **Does it expand to nothing** (i.e. 0 bytes)? If so, then `GB_GET_SECTION` would point to whatever `__VA_ARGS__` is. But then what would be the point of the `__attribute__ ((aligned (8)))` qualifier? Or **does the empty struct expand to some garbage padding bytes?** If it does, then `GB_GET_SECTION` would point to garbage data.

So which one is it?

Comment: Standard C does not allow empty structures.  Therefore, the code is probably using a compiler extension of some sort (GCC probably does allow empty structures).

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html#Empty-Structures

Comment: @NateEldredge Doesn't the `(aligned(8))` complicate that?

Comment: I think the short answer is exactly what it says: it's an object of size 0, whose address is guaranteed to be a multiple of 8.  I have a guess as to the intended purpose of this, but it's hard to be sure without more context, so  it'd help if you could link to the code where these macros are used.

Comment: By the way, it's not quite clear what you mean by "dereferencing" a struct; dereferencing is something you do to pointers, and a struct is not a pointer.

Comment: @NateEldredge By "dereferencing" I meant taking the "address of" to later use.

Comment: @nanoman taking the address is referencing (the opposite of dereferencing)

Comment: @NateEldredge As for the link for where else these macros are used, there are a few places. 

https://github.com/LIJI32/SameBoy/blob/master/Core/gb.h#L324
^  for `GB_SECTION`

https://github.com/LIJI32/SameBoy/blob/0c91502859496c21e174095eb8a56d74a236c58a/Core/save_state.c#L222
^  for `GB_GET_SECTION`

And I'll be sure to change the title then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty structs are not allowed by standard C, but are an [extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Empty-Structures.html#Empty-Structures) provided by gcc.   They are exactly what they seem, an object of size 0, and they do exactly what you expect, which is essentially nothing.  They have no members to be accessed.  You can assign one to another, but it's a no-op.  They're most useful as placeholders, as in this case.

`__attribute__((aligned (8)))` does the same thing it usually does: guarantees that an object with this attribute is aligned on an 8-byte boundary.  In other words, its address will be a multiple of 8.

In this program, the macros are used to divide the members of a large struct into "sections", each of which begins on an 8-byte boundary, and to create zero-byte empty struct members to mark the beginning and end of each section.  The code looks something like:

```
struct GB_gameboy_s {
    GB_SECTION(foo, int a; short b;);
    GB_SECTION(bar, char c; char d;);
};

typedef struct GB_gameboy_s GB_gameboy_t;
```

which expands to

```
struct GB_gameboy_s {
    __attribute__ ((aligned (8))) struct {} foo_section_start;
    int a;
    short b;
    struct {} foo_section_end;
    __attribute__ ((aligned (8))) struct {} bar_section_start;
    short c;
    char d;
    struct {} bar_section_end;
};
```

And so the layout of the struct is something like:

- `foo_section_start`: offset 0, size 0
- `a`: offset 0, size 4
- `b`: offset 4, size 2
- `foo_section_end`: offset 6, size 0
- `bar_section_start`: offset 8, size 0
- `c`: offset 8, size 2
- `d`: offset 10, size 1
- `bar_section_end`: offset 11, size 0

Note the `aligned` attribute has ensured that `bar_section_start`, and therefore also `c`, are placed at offset `8`, instead of at offset `6` as they otherwise might be.  There is padding in bytes 7 and 8 of the struct, but note that this padding comes *before* `bar_section_start`, as it must in order for alignment to make sense.   `bar_section_start` points to the first byte *after* the padding, not to the padding itself.

Now, one can use `offsetof` to find the offsets of these members, and use this to compute the size of each section, as `GB_SECTION_SIZE` does.  For instance, [here](https://github.com/LIJI32/SameBoy/blob/0c91502859496c21e174095eb8a56d74a236c58a/Core/save_state.c) you can see them writing various sets of members to a file, so as to save parts of the virtual machine's state, using code like

```
fwrite(GB_GET_SECTION(bar), GB_SECTION_SIZE(bar), 1, fd)
```

This has the effect of writing bytes 8 through 10 of the struct, i.e. the `c` and `d` members.  It's a little more convenient than writing out the desired members one by one, especially since in the real code there are a lot more than two.

It's not clear exactly why the alignment was needed, but it may be that it's more convenient somehow if everything written to the dump file is in multiples of 8 bytes.  It also can be somewhat more efficient to copy aligned buffers around.

They could have used `char` or some other standard type for the `start/end` members, but the struct would have become unnecessarily larger.  For instance, in that case, `a` could not be placed at offset 0 and would therefore be put at offset 4, in order to give it 4-byte alignment as is usual for `int`.  `b` would go at offset 8, and `bar_section_start` would be at offset 16.  This would then mean using 16 bytes for the `foo` section instead of 8, wasting a certain amount of memory and disk space (though indeed it's unlikely to be very significant)

Comment: SameBoy's author here. The alignment is there so changes to a section won't affect the following section.